# How to send data to php file other that the action=" " ?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am doing a simple login check and was wondering how to send data to a PHP file other than what is specified in the action tag.

Like in this code I want the **$cuslog=$_POST['cuslog'];** to go to other PHP file but the page to go to the HTML file specified in the action tag (**e.action='WEBSITE/gallery.html**)?

The idea is once the customer name data is checked (if it exists) then the page goes to gallery HTML and the customer id input is sent to another php file for knowing who is using the page currently.

My knowledge is limited to PHP, javascript, CSS, and HTML at the moment.

**HTML named login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>about</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
<body>
  <form  method="post" action="../login.php" class="form" >               
    <div class="login">Custormer ID<br><input type="text" name="cuslog">    
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
  </form>             
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP named login.php**

```
<?php
   $cuslog=$_POST['cuslog'];
?>

<html>
<head><title>Login</title>
<body>
<form id="to-login" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_username" value="<?php echo $cuslog; ?>" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST["cuslog"])){
        $cuslog=$_POST['cuslog'];
        $search=mysql_query("select CustomerID from orders where 
                                 CustomerID=$cuslog");
        $rows=mysql_num_rows($search);  
      //$data=mysql_fetch_row($search);
      if($rows !== 0){
           echo" <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  var e = document.getElementById('to-login');
                  e.action='WEBSITE/gallery.html';
                  e.submit();
                  </script>";
        }   
      else {
             echo "[Login]Account Doesn't Exist<br>";
        }   
   }

?>
```

Comment: why don't you use cookies for that?

Comment: You might need to use Ajax to send username to the php file

Comment: you should manage the user through a session and redirect the user to gallery if logged

Comment: I don't know Ajax @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: How? @DjordjeVujicic

Comment: As @LorenzoCatalano said. You can even set cookies that will last longer like facebook for example. When you check checkbox "stay logged in" whenever you open facebook you will be logged in after that...

Comment: thank you all. I solved it with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger inline img tag to pass Anonymous data.

```
<img src="customer_idtrack.php?customer_id=<?php echo $customerid; ?>" alt="InlineImgtag to pass customer id" height="0" width="0"/>
```

security : Additionally some hash to validate will do the job